# What's the build script for a module distribution?

Tags: raku

I have test failures. I want to see the details and experiment and perhaps debug, so I unpack the module dist. Now I expect to find some analogue to Setup.hs, setup.py, Build.PL, Rakefile etc., but there are no executables. How do you manually build and test verbosely?

Comment: Which module are you trying to install?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I just now sampled ten dists and none of them have a build script.

Answer (score 2):

### Installing modules

First I'd check more into `zef`

```
zef install module::name
zef test    /path/to/module
zef --help
```

`zef` comes with Rakudo-Star.

If you make a change and want to reinstall the module with the change and it doesn't want to install it, you can "force" it:

```
zef install --force-install ./relative/path/to/module
```

Or, if you bump the version in `META6.json`, you don't have to force it:

```
zef install ./relative/path/to/module
```

### Testing modules

To test a module, you can use `prove` to run all of the tests in its test directory:

```
prove --exec=perl6 -r t/
```

To run an individual test, simply use `perl6`:

```
perl6 t/test.t
```

### See also

[Running Tests](https://docs.perl6.org/language/testing.html#Running_tests)

You also might be interested in [`6pm`](https://github.com/FCO/6pm), but I don't have enough experience with it to comment on it at this time.